# How to get the filepath of an image dropped onto a button in VB

Tags: vb.net, string, drag-and-drop

I am attempting to get the filepath of an image that is dropped onto a button in VB. I have set the button to allow drop and I have set up this segment to hold the event code:

```
Private Sub btnDropZone_drop(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDropZone.DragDrop

    End Sub
```

How would I go about getting the filepath from this event as a string? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check designer of that form

Comment: What you mean? The form is set up, I just need to know how to get the filepath for an image that I drop onto it from windows explorer.

Comment: put some light or post a image of tht..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button is a pretty small drop target, but it would work the same as anything else: examine `e As DragEventArgs`:

```
Private Sub btnDropZone_drop(sender As Object, 
      e As EventArgs) Handles btnDropZone.DragDrop

    'ToDo check the format to see what was dropped
    Dim Files As String() = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

    For Each s As String In Files
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(s))
    Next
End Sub
```

When you are trying to figure out what to do in an event, always look up the meaning and contents of the eventargs

Comment: Thanks again :) do you ever sleep? I swear you helped me last night? xD